# error while inserting record in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio

I'm trying to run this query but I'm getting an error.

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[User]
       ([User_Name]
       ,[User_type]
       ,[Is_deleted]
       ,[User_Password])
 VALUES
       (admin, varchar(30),
       ,Admin, varchar(10),
       ,False, bit,
       ,admin, varchar(10),)
```

Erro message:

```
Msg 195, Level 15, State 10, Line 10
'varchar' is not a recognized built-in function name.
```

Comment: well, it throws an error because the code doesn't really makes sense. What is it that you want to do?

Comment: You do not specify data types on the values you submit to the INSERT statement. Instead, you just need to submit the correctly delimited data. The information in your VALUES statement should look like: `('admin'
       ,'Admin'
       ,0 /*False may work in some configurations, but not always*/
       ,'admin')`

Comment: It looks like you used a template for an INSERT statement that included the data types for the values. That is simply informational, not actually required data, which is why in most templates like this the information is commented out in the template code.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure you are looking for something like this.

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[User]
       ([User_Name]
       ,[User_type]
       ,[Is_deleted]
       ,[User_Password])
 VALUES
       ('admin'
       , 'Admin'
       , 0
       , 'admin'
      )
```

However, there are MANY problems visible here. First of all, you should NEVER store passwords in clear text. They should be salted and hashed. You also should have a lookup table with UserTypes and the data in the User table would have a foreign key to the other table.